# Different numbers in all cells of a 3x3 board

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, lights-out

This puzzle is inspired by this one: [Board with all 2020s](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101545/board-with-all-2020s)

Zeroes are written in all cells of a 3×3 board. Pressing a cell increases by 1 the number in this cell and all cells having a common side with it. Is it possible to obtain different numbers in each cell? **Bonus question:** what is the least number of presses needed to achieve this? Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make these presses:

> \begin{matrix} 0 &4 &2\\ 1 &2 &0\\ 0 &0 &0 \end{matrix}

To get these values:

> \begin{matrix} 5 &8 &6\\ 3 &7 &4\\ 1 &2 &0 \end{matrix}

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let nonnegative integer decision variable $x_{i,j}$ be the number of times that cell $(i,j)$ is pressed.  Let binary decision variable $y_{i,j,v}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ contains value $v$.  Let $N_{i,j}$ be the neighborhood of cell $(i,j)$, including $(i,j)$ itself.  The problem is to minimize
$$\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j} \tag1$$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_{v\in V} y_{i,j,v} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \tag2 \\
\sum_{i,j} y_{i,j,v} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $v$} \tag3 \\
\sum_{(\bar{i},\bar{j})\in N_{i,j}} x_{\bar{i},\bar{j}} &= \sum_{v\in V} v\ y_{i,j,v} &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \tag4
\end{align}
The objective function $(1)$ is the total number of presses.  Constraint $(2)$ enforces one value per cell. Constraint $(3)$ enforces at most one cell per value.  Constraint $(4)$ links the number of presses in the neighborhood to the value in the cell.

Comment: You got it! - this is optimal. I actually thought of Integer Programming when making this puzzle.

Comment: Why is this optimal?

Comment: I'll describe the integer linear programming formulation later, but an easy lower bound is 8 presses because you need 9 different nonnegative integers, the largest of which must be at least 8.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible:

> Press the corners 1, 3, 6, and 2 times. This gives the resulting grid of [143/705/682].

Comment: Correct answer to the first question! Note this does not use the minimal number of presses.