# Different numbers in all cells of a 4x4 board

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, lights-out

This is a harder version of this puzzle: [Different numbers in all cells of a 3x3 board](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101611/different-numbers-in-all-cells-of-a-3x3-board)

Zeroes are written in all cells of a 4×4 board. Pressing a cell increases by 1 the number in this cell and all cells having a common side with it. Is it possible to obtain different numbers in each cell? **Bonus question:** what is the least number of presses needed to achieve this? Good luck!

Comment: I wonder if the bonus question is just there to throw us off, as it assumes the answer to the previous question would be yes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the least amount of presses is

> 27

Press the following cells $x$ amount of times

> \begin{matrix} 0 &1 &2 &1\\ 0 &7 &1 &1\\ 0 &2 &4 &6 \\ 0 &0 &1 &1 \end{matrix}

yielding

> \begin{matrix} 1 &10 &5 &4\\ 7 &11 &15 &9\\ 2 &13 &14 &12 \\ 0 &3 &6 &8 \end{matrix}

Comment: Well done! That is optimal indeed.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky How do you know?

Comment: looking at this and the previous puzzle, I am wondering if an n x n grid would take 3^(n-1) moves?

Comment: @SeanC, the minimum for $n=5$ is 63, not 81.

Comment: Wow 63. I only managed 67.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky 128 for $n=6$ and 237 for $n=7$

Answer (score 5):

Answer to the first question

> Yes it is possible

Make these presses

> \begin{matrix} 1 &0 &0 &0\\ 1 &0 &8 &0\\ 1 &2 &8 & 2 \\ 1 &2 &2 &2 \end{matrix}

To get these values

> \begin{matrix} 2 &1 &8 &0\\ 3 &11 &16 &10\\ 5 &13 &22 & 12 \\ 4 &7 &14 &6 \end{matrix}

Not sure if this is optimal.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another optimal solution, obtained via integer linear programming.  Make these presses:

> \begin{matrix} 0 &0 &1 &0 \\ 8 &5 &0 &3 \\ 0 &1 &6 &2 \\ 0 &0 &1 &0 \end{matrix}

To get these values:

> \begin{matrix} 8 &6 &1 &4 \\ 13 &14 &15 &5 \\ 9 &12 &10 &11 \\ 0 &2 &7 &3 \end{matrix}

---

By request, here's the ILP formulation I used.  For each cell $(i,j)$, let $$N_{ij} = \{(i_2,j_2): |i-i_2| + |j-j_2| \le 1\}$$ be the neighborhood of the cell.
For each cell $(i,j)$, let nonnegative integer decision variable $x_{ij}$ represent the number of times to press the cell.
For each cell $(i,j)$ and value $k\in\{0,\dots,M\}$, let binary decision variable $y_{ijk}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ takes value $k$.
The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i,j} x_{ij}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_k y_{ijk} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i,j$} \\
\sum_{i,j} y_{ijk} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $k$} \\
\sum_{(i_2,j_2) \in N_{ij}} x_{i_2,j_2} &= \sum_k k y_{ijk} &&\text{for all $i,j$}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice. Is ILP able to produce multiple optimal solutions? I am interested to know how many there are, at least for the 3x3 case. I found a few, but there could be others lurking.

Comment: 56 optimal solutions for 3x3 and 3280 for 4x4

Comment: Thank you RobPratt!

Comment: Hi RobPratt, I'm trying to build this model. I use $n^2$ integers variables to determine how many times to press, and $O(n^4)$ binary variables to realize the inequal constraints of every pair. I also tried using $(Mn^2)$ binary variables to realize the inequal constraints, where $M$ is a predefined upper bound of the result matrix. But that seems worse. I wonder how you build the model, and how long do you need to solve the model of $n=6, 7$, thank you.

Comment: @xdy I added my formulation.  For $n=6$, it took 8 minutes.  For $n=7$, it took 28 minutes.  I used $M=n^2-1$ for both.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you! That is very helpful.